# Question of difference between append_row and append_rows

Tags: python, gspread

What is the difference between append_row and append_rows?

In append_row, `worksheet.append_row (['test', 'test2'])` works

At append_rows,
`Worksheet.append_rows(['test', 'test2'])` is not working.

But

```
test = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
val = worksheet.append_rows ([test])
```

is activated.

What's the difference between the two? It would be nice if there was an example for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the document of gspread, `append_row` appends a row to the sheet. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v3.7.0/api.html?highlight=append_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_row) On the other hand, `append_rows` appends multiple rows to the sheet. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v3.7.0/api.html?highlight=append_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_rows)

#### Sample script:

##### `append_row`

In this case, one row is appended. So, the 1-dimensional array is used as follows.

```
worksheet.append_row(["test1", "test2"])
```

##### `append_rows`

In this case, multiple rows are appended. So, the 2-dimensional array is used as follows.

```
worksheet.append_rows([["test1", "test2"], ["test3", "test4"]])
```

#### Note:

- As an additional information, when I saw the script of gspread, it seems that when `append_row` is run, the value is used with `append_rows` method. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/a666fa35ade4c8cd215c6e0eee9d2ff5cc000a08/gspread/worksheet.py#L1259) So, it seems that the endpoint of Sheets API is the same between `append_row` and `append_rows`.

#### References:

- [append_row(values, value_input_option='RAW', insert_data_option=None, table_range=None)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v3.7.0/api.html?highlight=append_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_row)
- [append_rows(values, value_input_option='RAW', insert_data_option=None, table_range=None)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v3.7.0/api.html?highlight=append_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_rows)